# Why is Buzz Lightyear's catchphrase British?

Tags: character, analysis, dialogue

Buzz Lightyear is a toy manufactured in the USA. Also his voice-actor (Tim Allen) is American, and his name is inspired by American astronaut Buzz Aldrin.

But Buzz's catchphrase (**blast!**) is British.

He used it for the first time in *Toy Story*:

> **Buzz**: Blast! This'll take weeks to repair.

From [Oxford's Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/blast_3):

> (especially British English, informal)
>
> ​people sometimes say Blast! when they are annoyed about something.
>
> - Oh blast! The car won't start.

Why does Buzz use an informal British thing as his catchphrase?

** Blast in general is used in both British and American English. It's only the exclamation usage that is mostly British.

Comment: Because it sounds like a 'ray gun' noise from 50's sci-fi?

Comment: Because he can't actually *swear* so they had to pick something else.

Comment: I'm not American so can't say for sure but isn't "Blast!" as an exclamation more of a mid-century 1940s-1970s term? [Cambridge Dictionaries has it as UK & US but dubs it "old fashioned"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blast). To me its American usage feels (much like Buzz himself) more at home in that era of clean-cut excitement about space exploration, alongside the likes of Buck Rogers, the Jetsons, etc.

Comment: This American finds nothing odd about it.

Comment: I'm almost certain Buzz Lightyear's catchphrase wasn't "Blast!", it was "To infinity... and beyond!"

Comment: Do you see the 'especially' in the dictionary definition you quote?

Comment: My dad, born 1920, used to say (or shout) the full version, 'Damn and blast!'. The first word used to be problematic until maybe the 1960s. Now it's just archaic. In fact, 'blast' also had the same meaning 200 or 300 years ago: _Blast 10. a.II.10.a trans. To strike or visit with the wrath and curse of heaven; to curse. Often in imprecations in the imperative or optative form (for God blast…); also as an exclamation of annoyance._ Oxford English Dictionary

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's mostly used in British English (that's the *especially* in the definition), but it's not unheard of in American English. I found dozens of examples by searching `PUNC blast PUNC` in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), including a number in TV shows like the 1993 Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles series. (Remember, in children's TV and movies they can't use the curse words adults typically use.)

In the case of Buzz, it's probably playing off "blast off", defined by [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/blast-off_1) as:

> ​(of spacecraft) to leave the ground
>
> The rocket blasted off at noon.

Comment: Absolutely has to do with blasting off, and space travel. I mean, *Buzz Lightyear* and *To infinity and beyond!* *Blimey!* just wouldn't have the same effect.

Answer (score 4):

Less common or unusual catchphrases are sometimes used by the more eccentric characters in a film or TV show, like "Dyno-mite" (J.J. in the sitcom *Good Times*), and "Shazam!" (Gomer Pyle in *The Andy Griffith Show* and the later eponymous spinoff). Using phrases that are less common, yet still understood by audiences, can help to enhance the perceived eccentricity of the character.